# replacing characters with javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace underscores with slashes when they are before a four digit number, for example

```
res_234_2010-xxx -> res_234/2010-xxx
res_12345_1999-yyy -> res_12345/1999-yyy
```

(In fact, the four digit number should be a valid year, startin with 19xx or 20xx)

Is there some way to achieve it with .replace method, or shall I do it programmatically?

Comment: Use a lookahead. http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html. Please show what you've tried, we can't help you fix your code if you don't first make an attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
var result = str.replace(/_((?:19|20)\d{2})\b/g, '/$1');
```

[**Regular Expression Explanation**](http://regexdoc.com/re/explain.pl?re=_%28%28%3F%3A19%7C20%29%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%5Cb&.submit=Explain%21&mode=SO&.cgifields=mode)

Comment: Great answer, I would give you extra points for adding the regex explanation

Comment: @opensas, using lookahead. `var result = str.replace(/_(?=(?:19|20)\d{2}\b)/g, '/');`